# Calculating rolling correlations in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a data set [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/94bxofh1o8f7t2w/data_rolling.xlsx).

An excerpt of my data looks like this: (For an enlarged version: http://puu.sh/79NCK.jpg)

[image]

(Note: there are **no** missing values in my dataset)

I wish to calculate the correlation matrix using a rolling window of 1 year. My period starts from 01 Jan 2008. So for example, the correlation between `AUT` and `BEL` on 01 Jan 2008 is calculated using the series of values from 01 Jan 2007 to 01 Jan 2008, and likewise for all other pairs. Similarly the correlation between `AUT` and `BEL` on 02 Jan 2008 is calculated using the series of values from 02 Jan 2007 to 02 Jan 2008.

Since there will be a different correlation matrix for each day, I want to output each day's correlation matrix into a sheet in excel and name that sheet COV1 (for 01 Jan 2008), COV2 (for 02 Jan 2008), COV3 (for 03 Jan 2008), and so on until COV1566 (for 31 Dec 2013). An excerpt of the output for each sheet is like this: (Note: with the titles included on the top row and first column)

http://puu.sh/79NAy.jpg

I have loaded my datafile into SAS named `rolling`. For the moment, my code is simply:

```
proc corr data = mm.rolling;
run;
```

Which simply calculates the correlation matrix using the entire series of values. I am very new to SAS, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about how you might do if you had immense amount of patience.

```
proc corr data = mm.rolling out = correlation_as_of_01jan2008;
where date between '01jan2007'd and '01jan2008'd;
run;
```

Similarly,

```
proc corr data = mm.rolling out = correlation_as_of_02jan2008;
where date between '02jan2007'd and '02jan2008'd;
run;
```

Thankfully you can use SAS macro programming to achieve a similar effect as shown in this macro:

```
%macro rollingCorrelations(inputDataset=, refDate=);
/*first get a list of unique dates on or after the reference date*/
proc freq data = &inputDataset. noprint;
where date >="&refDate."d;
table date/out = dates(keep = date);
run;


/*for each date calculate what the window range is, here using a year's length*/
data dateRanges(drop = date);
set dates end = endOfFile 
                nobs= numDates;
format toDate fromDate date9.;

toDate=date;
fromDate = intnx('year', toDate, -1, 's');

call symputx(compress("toDate"!!_n_), put(toDate,date9.));
call symputx(compress("fromDate"!!_n_), put(fromDate, date9.) );

/*find how many times(numberOfWindows) we need to iterate through*/
if endOfFile then do;
call symputx("numberOfWindows", numDates);
end;

run;
%do i = 1 %to &numberOfWindows.;
/*create a temporary view which has the filtered data that is passed to PROC CORR*/
data windowedDataview / view = windowedDataview;
set  &inputDataset.;
where date between "&&fromDate&i."d and "&&toDate&i."d;
drop date;
run;
    /*the output dataset from each PROC CORR run will be 
correlation_DDMMMYYY<from date>_DDMMMYY<start date>*/
proc corr data = windowedDataview 
outp = correlations_&&fromDate&i.._&&toDate&i. (where=(_type_ = 'CORR'))

        noprint;
run;

%end;

/*append all datasets into a single table*/
data all_correlations;
format from to date9.;
set correlations_:
     indsname = datasetname
;
from = input(substr(datasetname,19,9),date9.);
to = input(substr(datasetname,29,9), date9.);
run;


%mend rollingCorrelations;
%rollingCorrelations(inputDataset=rolling, refDate=01JAN2008)
```

The final output from the above macro will have `from` & `to` identifier to identify which date range each correlation matrix refers. Run it and examine the results.

I dont think excel can accomodate over 1500 tabs anyway, so best to keep it in a single table. The final table had 81K rows and the whole process ran in 2.5 mins.

update: to sort them by `from` & `to`

```
proc sort data = ALL_CORRELATIONS;
by from to;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you, what a thorough answer. I tried to run the code, however I get an error: `WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference NUMBEROFWINDOWS no resolved. ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required. The condition was: &numberOfWindowss. ERROR: The %TO value of the %DO I loop is invalid. ERROR: The macro ROLLINGCORRELATIONS will stop executing.`

Comment: I think that was because I was missing the `run;` statement just above `%do i = 1 %to &numberOfWindows.;` line. Fixed now, please try again.

Comment: Thank you, the code works now. However, I am looking through the output now, and there seems to be missing values, for example, from 1 APR 08 to 1 APR 09, the row with the correlations of  `ALPHA` with all other pairs are missing values, this shouldn't happen since there are no missing data in my dataset. Also I was wondering if the output could be slightly adjusted so that it is in order according to the "to" date, that is, the first correlation matrix should be for the day 01JAN08, the second should be for 02JAN08, etc. Currently, the output follows another "order". Thank you!

Comment: The reason you get missing values for `ALPHA` between `01APR2008` & `01APR2009` is because, even though you do not have any missing values, `ALPHA` has 0 in all rows during that period meaning that it had 0-standard deviation. This will result in divison by zero  in the correlation coef. formula and cause a missing value. You just need `PROC SORT` to order them the right way - updated my answer.

Comment: Notice the `GRE` column all periods on and after `from:11MAR2012` & `to: 11MAR2013` have a missing value in that column. This is because in your dataset `GRE` has 0s after `09MAR2012`

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense! Thank you so much for your help so far. So then one last thing is, can we somehow make an "if" condition where if the correlation is empty (due to all 0's), then make that value equal to the correlation using the fixed time period from 01 Jan 2008 to 31 Dec 2013. E.g., say GRE has missing values on 01 APR 08, 30 DEC 09 (just made those dates up), then just simply set those missing values as the correlation between GRE and other label using ALL values from 01 Jan 2008 to 31 Dec 2013. And apply this to any other pairs that have missing values. Thanks!

Comment: That is certainly possible, but you should ask that question as a separate question. Do provide sample mock up data that is representative of your problem.

Comment: Will do. The new question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22043382/filling-in-missing-values-of-a-rolling-correlation-matrix